# How can I rescale / format chart elements in a bar chart?

Tags: graphics, visualization, charts

In this simple [MWE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354), I create a simple chart element of a female figure, and then I apply it to a barchart, with the following code (note: womfig = this little stick figure [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx1a5.jpg)).

```
bd = BarChart[{0.76, 8.34},
 ChartLabels -> {"With screening", "No screening"} ,
 ChartElements -> {womfig, {1, 1}}, BarOrigin -> Left,
 PlotLabel -> Style["Lifetime cervical cancer deaths
  per 1000 women", FontSize -> 18], PlotRange -> Full,
ImageSize -> Large, BarSpacing -> 0]
```

This is a good start, producing this figure, but with a lot of wasted space:

[image]

I have been less successful in trying to eradicate the dead space unfortunately; when I try to truncate to just the bars of interest, it creates a unwanted space between the bars.

For example, if I add PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 8.5}, {0.5, 2}}, it makes things a lot worse. I imagine this has to do with rescaling of the chart elements when you adjust the plot region: but is there an easy way to produce something like the below?

I ask because eventually this will need to take varying values, so manual tweaking is a nuisance...

[image]

Comment: Notice also that portion of last figure bigger than 0.34. That's also wrong. Similarly for bottom one. It should be 0.76 of figure not hole figure.

Comment: That's an excellent point - weirdly, in an old mathematica notebook for an earlier release, it seemed to work fine and produced this (correct) output... https://imgur.com/7mcdxnR

Comment: `AxesOrigin -> {2, 0}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 2.5}}` seems to solve both your problem and the problem @OkkesDulgerci mentioned. `PlotLabel` could be better  positioned by wrapping the plot in a `Labeled` function. Tested in Mathematica 12.3

Comment: You may find this answer useful, [DS 10814](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/65217/10814)

Answer (score 8):

```
 womfig = Import["https://i.imgur.com/n6m1Rkc.png"];
```

**1.** You can use the (undocumented) option `"FixedBarSpacing"` to remove the extra space above and below the bars and use the spec `{womfig, {1, All}}` for `ChartElements` to have the figure stretch vertically to fill the bounding box of the bar:

```
 BarChart[{0.76, 8.34}, 
  ChartLabels -> {"With screening", "No screening"}, 
  ChartElements -> {womfig, {1, All}}, 
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Lifetime cervical cancer deaths\nper 1000 women", FontSize -> 18], 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  "FixedBarSpacing" -> True, 
  BarSpacing -> 0]
```

[image]

Play with `AspectRatio` option values to get the desired proportion for vertical and horizontal lengths of bars. For example, add the option  `AspectRatio -> 1/4` to get:

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, use `{{0.76, 8.34}}` (instead of `{0.76, 8.34}`) as the first argument of `BarChart` with the option `BarSpacing -> {0, 1}` to get the same result:

```
BarChart[{{0.76, 8.34}}, 
  ChartLabels -> {"With screening", "No screening"}, 
  ChartElements -> {womfig, {1, All}},
  BarOrigin -> Left, 
  PlotLabel -> Style["Lifetime cervical cancer deaths\nper 1000 women", FontSize -> 18], 
  ImageSize -> Large, 
  BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
  AspectRatio -> 1/4]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, this is perfect - thank you!

Comment: @DRG, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that you want to play a bit with AspectRatio and the size of the  womfig bar.

Just a start:

[image]

```
bd = BarChart[{0.76, 8.34},
    ChartLabels -> {"With screening", "No screening"},
    ChartElements -> {womfig, {1, 1}},
    BarOrigin -> Left,
    PlotLabel -> Style["Lifetime cervical cancer deaths
        per 1000 women", FontSize -> 18],
    PlotRange -> Full,
    ImageSize -> Large, BarSpacing -> 0,
    AspectRatio -> #] & /@ {1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25}
```

[image]